# Javascript Inline Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm creating an inline CRUD operations in MVC 5 wherein for adding new records the user will click a certain button and it will create a new dynamic table row. this is my javascript code:

```
        function tblnewrow() {

            var newrow = '<tr>' +
             '<td><span class="edit-mode"><input type="text" class="form-control edit-mode" id="particular" placeholder="Enter Particular"/></span></td>' +
             '<td><span class="edit-mode"><input type="text" class="form-control edit-mode" id="acctcode" placeholder="Enter Account Code" /></span></td>' +
             '<td><span class="edit-mode"><input type="text" class="form-control edit-mode" id="ppmpcode" placeholder="Enter PPMP Code" /></span></td>' +
             '<td><span class="edit-mode">@Html.DropDownList("Account Code", (SelectList)ViewBag.listValues, "---Select Account Code---", new { @class = "form-control edit-mode", id = "acctcode" })</span></td>' +
             '<td align="center"><button class="btn btn-success edit-mode" id="saveParticular" type="submit">Save</button><button class="btn btn-danger cancel-add edit-mode">Cancel</button></td>'

            $('#particularTbl tr:last').after(newrow);
        };
```

i can successfully add a new row but when i added the dropdownlist it is not working. what am i doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you have will correctly add the `<select>` element assuming this script is not in an external `.js` file. (but your creating invalid html - duplicate `id` attributes - and how you expect the submit button to work is anyone's guess and what on earth is the point of having multiple submit buttons anyway)

Comment: i've deleted the other code block with the same id but still it's not showing the row. i can get it populated though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use sever helpers in JQ and expect to render it correctly on client side. You will need to replace

```
'<td><span class="edit-mode">@Html.DropDownList("Account Code", (SelectList)ViewBag.listValues, "---Select Account Code---", new { @class = "form-control edit-mode", id = "acctcode" })</span></td>'
```

with pure html code like

```
'<td><span class="edit-mode"><select class="form-control edit-mode" id="acctcode"><option value='1'>---Select Account Code---</option></select></span></td>'
```

As for the option list you can pass values form ViewBag to JQ like this:

```
var bag = "<%= ViewBag.listValues%>"
```

Then you will need to construct your option list from that.

Comment: Of course you can use the `HtmlHelper` methods in javascript (assuming its not in an external file)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `.ToHtmlString()`

```
@Html.DropDownList("Account Code", (SelectList)ViewBag.listValues, "---Select Account Code---", new { @class = "form-control edit-mode", id = "acctcode" }).ToHtmlString()
```

Comment: nope. still not showing. thanks for the reply though, :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried out something like yours. My code -

```
<div id="div"></div>

<script>

    window.onload = function(){
        var sel = '@Html.DropDownList("List")';
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = sel;
    };

</script>
```

When i use view page source i get -

```
<div id="div"></div>

<script>

    window.onload = function(){
        var sel = '<select id="List" name="List"><option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>';
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = sel;
    };

</script>
```

as you can see the select list was generated but the problem is that there are line breaks which makes this an invalid javascript string. and an error is thrown -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I am assuming your problem is also same.

But if your browser supports ECMASCript6 (like latest chrome) you can use backtick and it should work. Mine did.

```
var sel = `@Html.DropDownList("List")`;
```

Comment: this is the generated html where the error occurs:                                 '<td><span class="edit-mode"><select id="listAccounts" name="listAccounts"><option value="401">401</option>

Comment: run your application, goto view page source and paste the generate `var newrow` string in your question. also see if there are any error messages in the browser console.